# Derive an exact formula (solve the recurrence definition) for the following recursive sequence:

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

Derive an exact formula (solve the recurrence definition) for the following recursive sequence: $s_n = 2_{s_n-1} - s_{n-2}$ where $n \ge 2$, and $s_0 = 4$, $s_1 = 1$.

So I saw someone solving this by making it a differential equation or something?

How would you do that? should I do 
let $\alpha = C_1$ let $\beta = C_2$ (because those symbols are ugly as hell)

$r^2 - 2r + 1$ to get:

$r = 1$, $r = 1$

= $C_11^n + C_2n1^n$ ?
But how do I find my $C_1$ and $C_2$ ?

Comment: Doesn't help...

Comment: sorry, try $s_n = r^{n+2}$ (discrete) or $s_n = e^{n+2}$ (continuous), move everything to one side, then factor

Comment: Check out my updated work. Now I'm just trying to figure out how to solve for $C_2$ and $C_1$

Comment: There's no rule that you *have* to use Greek letters vs. any other alphabet or symbol.

Comment: What GFauxPas said, but they aren't ugly. Don't forget that you probably have seen and used many other Greek letters such as $γ,δ,ε,π,φ,λ,μ,σ,ρ,θ,Σ,Π$. While I think it's more convenient to use English letters, Mathematics would look very different without Greek letters. How, pray tell, would you write a summation? Or perhaps you like some letters but not others. Do you have similar preferences for some English letters over others? I personally don't like the "a" in this font. What a terrible look!

Comment: @GFauxPas: But there's an unspoken golden rule of arithmetic symbols: don't use brackets or things like $+,-,\times,\div$!

Comment: Yea there isn't a rule but it is the standard for this type of problem in a discrete mathematics class. Also, no, alpha and beta are the ugliest symbols created. I'd rather use mew or the dirac delta function. So yea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use the first one. The idea is to suppose you have an operator $r$ that takes each element of the sequence to the next one--that is, $rs_n=s_{n+1}$ for all $n$. Then $$r^2s_n=2rs_n-s_n$$ for all $n$ by the recurrence, and so $$(r^2-2r+1)s_n=0$$ for all $n.$ Since $s_0=1,$ then it follows that $$r^2-2r+1$$ is the zero operator (sends everything to $0$). Its only eigenvalues, then, are solutions to $0=x^2-2x+1=(x-1)^2.$

Consequently, we conclude from the recursion that $$s_n=\alpha\cdot 1^n+\beta n\cdot1^n=\alpha+\beta n.$$ Now apply your initial conditions.

Comment: so $C_1 = 4$ correct?

Comment: and $C_2 = -3$? i think

Comment: $\therefore S_n = 4^n - 3n1^n$ ?

Comment: $C_1=4,$ and so $C_2=-3.$ Then, $s_n=4-3n.$

Comment: There *is* no $4^n.$ Also, given any $n,$ what is $1^n$?

Comment: im a idiot. thx

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help.